# MySQL \G equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How does one format wide listings vertically like in MySQL using the `sqlcmd` client? Or should I be using `osql` instead?

And must I write "GO" each time to execute my query? Is there a shorthand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-y` or `-Y` to limit the width of wide columns in SQLCMD, but I'm not sure there's a way to wrap the contents of the column within that width, which is what I believe you're asking.

Also, you can use `-c` to specify a custom command terminator instead of `GO`, which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the isql client (http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/UserManual/) which is installed as part of the unixODBC package:

> debian:

```
$ sudo apt-get install unixODBC
```

> redhat:

```
sudo yum install unixODBC-devel.x86_64 unixODBC.x86_64
```

Usage example:

```
$ isql dsn_name username password
```

where "dsn_name" is defined in your ~/.odbc.ini as:

```
[dsn_name]
Driver=FreeTDS
Server=your.server.com
Port = 1433
Database = your_database_name
```

and FreeTDS is defined in /etc/odbcinst.ini as:

```
[FreeTDS]

Description = FreeTDS Driver for MSSQL
Driver      = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
Setup       = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
FileUsage   = 1
```